# Create a local-only port to communicate between processes on the same computer?

Tags: macos, unix, network-programming, ipc

I have two processes that are run by the same user, but neither is related to the other (in the parent/child sense). The server creates a socket, and the client opens a connection using its port number. This works great, however it would be better if there were a way to make this port local/private. No other computer needs to connect to my server, so it would be nice to protect it from remote port scans. Also, if the port weren't opened up to the outside world, I could potentially avoid bumping into the OS's firewall.

It looks like PF_UNIX might let me create a filename-type socket that works in this way, but is there a way to do it with a port-type (PF_INET) interface?

Comment: you can also get limited interprocess communication in  bash/ksh. Try looking for mknod, mkfifo, named pipes, and `|&` operator (if that's the right term). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using the loopback interface (127.0.0.1, localhost etc.) - processes on your system can all see it but nothing outside can.

Edit: To be specific, the whole 127.0.0.1/8 block is reserved for loopback, so 127.0.0.[1-254] will work.

Comment: Incidentally, I believe one may use 127.x.y.z for any any x.y.z other than 0.0.0; I don't know what the exact rules are, and a question I asked about the subject seemed pretty unpopular, but it might be a useful thing to know.

Comment: Very true, but the details are - as you suggest - a bit complex. I'll look it up and add. Edit: or maybe not... I thought I remembered some hidden complexity, but it seems straightforward now I look it up. Odd.

Comment: @jimw Aha. I was aware that one could connect to loopback addresses but didn't realize that a server could be restricted to only responding to that interface. Are you saying that I can just change the INADDR_ANY in my sockaddr_in.sin_addr.s_addr to INADDR_LOOPBACK?

Comment: Exactly, the INADDR_* macros tell bind which interface to use.

Comment: @jimw I tried it, and it seems to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the quick answer!